# Show Data For Grouped Series in ToolTip Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, highcharts

I am creating chart using Highcharts but i want to show a value in tooltip for every grouped series it is dynamic and chart is creating in ajax success therefore every groped series have different value to show in tooltip

Here is a image of chart :

[image]

This tooltip is shown for every group with heading of Categories each so i want to add a sub heading with dynamic value coming from ajax success

This is fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/KWPsv/80/

This what i tried but unable to achieve
http://jsfiddle.net/KWPsv/82/

My Code :

```
            success: function (data1) {
                debugger;
                var Series = JSON.parse(data1.d.ChartSeries);
                var Categories = JSON.parse(data1.d.Categories);
                var mYtitle = data1.d.TitleName;

       Highcharts.setOptions ({
        colors:[
            '#5a9bd4',
            '#faa75b',
            '#7ac36a',
            '#9e67ab',
            '#f15a60',
            '#ce7058',
            '#d77fb4'
        ]
    });

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo:'containerHR',
        type:'column'
    },
    title:{
        text:'Chart Title'
    },
    credits:{enabled:false},
    legend:{
    },
    tooltip:{
        shared:true        
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            shadow:false,
            borderWidth:0,
            pointPadding:0
        }
    },
    xAxis:{
        categories:Categories[0].categories,
        lineColor:'#999',
        lineWidth:1,
        tickColor:'#666',
        tickLength:3,
        title:{
            text:'X Axis Title',
            style:{
                color:'#333'
            }
        },
        labels: {
        useHTML: true,

    }
    },
    yAxis:{
        lineColor:'#999',
        lineWidth:1,
        tickColor:'#666',
        tickWidth:1,
        tickLength:3,
        gridLineColor:'#ddd',
        title:{
            text:'Y Axis Title',
            rotation:0,
            margin:50,
            style:{
                color:'#333'
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        shared: true,
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',

    },

    legend: {
        useHTML: true

    },


    series: Series


});
```

Comment: It looks that you are loading myData to series instead of a point. You should be able to get this value in series.options.myData: http://jsfiddle.net/KWPsv/84/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński yeah but i need a sub heading for whole tooltip because every value is only for one group. like Designation 1 to Designation 6 will get subheading in tooltip of 10 and so on other group

Comment: If you are going to trigger an ajax call every time user hovers on a point it will be a hell for the user. I would advice you to fetch all that data before hand and combine with the data you are plotting with additional key value pairs. Use them while rendering the tooltip.

Comment: Striker i am not triggering ajax call on user hover i am bringing value once  but i have to show that value in tooltip as subheading.

Comment: So you would like to achieve something similar to this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KWPsv/85/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński yes thankyou very much, but also the name of categories in tooltip also

Comment: With small changes in previous code it should be possible: http://jsfiddle.net/KWPsv/86/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thankx you can post in answer so i will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use tooltip formatter and inside this formatter return string with all of the values you would like to display in your chart:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

```
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    formatter: function() {
      var s = [],
        xAxis = this.points[0].series.xAxis,
        categoryIndex = xAxis.categories.indexOf(this.x),
        title = this.x,
        subTitle = xAxis.options.subtitles[categoryIndex];
      s.push(title + '<br>');
      s.push(subTitle + '<br>');
      $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
        s.push('<span style="color:#D31B22;font-weight:bold;">' + point.series.name + ' : ' +
          point.y + '<span>');
      });

      return s.join(' and ');
    },
  },
```

Live example showing chart with tooltip.formatter:
http://jsfiddle.net/KWPsv/86/